# What is the swift way of converting this string into PGN notation?

Tags: swift

I have the following string

```
let a:String = "r0bqkb0r/pppppppp/00n00n00/00000000/000P0000/0000B000/PPP0PPPP/RN0QKBNR/"
```

and want to convert this to PGN notation so the final result should be

```
result = "r1bqkb1r/pppppppp/2n2n2/8/3P4/4B3/PPP1PPPP/RN1QKBNR/"
```

The PGN notation converts the zeros to counts found.  Normally in python, I would just use

> import chess.pgn

Before deep diving into python library, is there is a succinct and 'Swift' way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `reduce` and a separate counter

*Update, rewrote it as an extension to String*

```
extension String {
    func pgpNotation() -> String {
        var zeroCounter = 0
        var result = self.reduce(into: "") { 
            if $1 == "0" {
                zeroCounter += 1
                return
            } 

            if zeroCounter > 0 {
                $0.append("\(zeroCounter)")
                zeroCounter = 0
            }
            $0.append($1)
        }
        if zeroCounter > 0 { result.append("\(zeroCounter)")}
        return result
    }
}
```

Examples

```
let x = "r00d00"
print(x.pgpNotation())

let a:String = "r0bqkb0r/pppppppp/00n00n00/00000000/000P0000/0000B000/PPP0PPPP/RN0QKBNR/"
print(a.pgpNotation())
```

> r2d2
>   r1bqkb1r/pppppppp/2n2n2/8/3P4/4B3/PPP1PPPP/RN1QKBNR/

Comment: since you're only doing appends, you can use `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct function for that but I just created a program for fun. You can check this out:-

```
let str = "r0bqkb0r/pppppppp/00n00n00/00000000/000P0000/0000B000/PPP0PPPP/RN0QKBNR/"
   var newStr = ""
   var flag = 0

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    for char in str {
        if flag == 0 {
            if char == "0" {
                flag += 1
            }
            else {
                newStr.append(char)
            }
        }
        else {
            if char == "0" {
                flag += 1
            }
            else {
                newStr.append("\(flag)")
                flag = 0
                if char == "0" {
                    flag += 1
                }
                else {
                    newStr.append(char)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(newStr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate taking the time to respond.  It does look more like good old C code than swift.  :-)

Comment: Yes but you can say, a swift code in a simple way and without using any higher order functions.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't exist any direct method to get the **pgn** notation `String`. You can use a **`forEach(_:)`** instead, i.e.

```
let a = "r0bqkb0r/pppppppp/00n00n00/00000000/000P0000/0000B000/PPP0PPPP/RN0QKBNR/"
var result = ""
var count = 0
a.forEach {
    if $0 == "0" {
        count += 1
    } else {
        if count != 0 {
            result.append("\(count)")
            count = 0
        }
        result.append($0)
    }
}
print(result) //r1bqkb1r/pppppppp/2n2n2/8/3P4/4B3/PPP1PPPP/RN1QKBNR/
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple regex and a loop (just to propose an original solution):

```
let a = "r0bqkb0r/pppppppp/00n00n00/00000000/000P0000/0000B000/PPP0PPPP/RN0QKBNR/"

extension String {
    var chessPGN : String {
        var result = self
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "0+")

        while let match = regex.matches(in: result, range: .init(location: 0, length: result.count)).first {
            if let stringRange = Range(match.range , in: result) {
                result.replaceSubrange(stringRange, with: match.range.length.description)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}


print(a.chessPGN) // r1bqkb1r/pppppppp/2n2n2/8/3P4/4B3/PPP1PPPP/RN1QKBNR/
```

**EDIT**: A version calling only once the regex

```
extension String {
    var chessPGN : String {
        var result = self
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "0+")

        for match in regex.matches(in: result, range: .init(location: 0, length: result.count)).sorted(by: { $0.range.location > $1.range.location }) {
            if let stringRange = Range(match.range , in: result) {
                result.replaceSubrange(stringRange, with: match.range.length.description)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I started down this path as well but was looking for a more "Swift" method.  I appreciate your time and effort.